# Passing a struct with multiple entries in c++

Tags: c++, struct, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a coordinate, which is defined as struct with 2 integer parameters (the struct is called coord) the following way:

```
UpdateB({0,0});
```

where the input argument is of type coord (i.e. in the above statement I am trying to pass a coordinate `0,0`). `UpdateB` is some function. I am getting an error, any ideas what 
the problem could be?

Comment: syntax errors, such as missing ;  }  {   etc. I think it doesn't like the curly bracket notation in UpdateB({0,0}), but I don't see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 7):

Make a constructor accepting two argumnets.
Pass it as follows:

`MyFunc(Point2d(0,0));`

Answer (score 2):

Pavel's got it spot on. If you want to create the struct instance as you're passing it to the function, you'll need to make a constructor for it. Then create a new instance of coord as the argument you're passing to the function. For the struct, something like...

```
struct coord
{
    int x, y;

    coord(int xvalue, int yvalue)
    {
        x = xvalue;
        y = yvalue;
    }
};
```

...should do the trick. Then just run...

```
UpdateB(coord(x, y));
```

...where x and y are your values.

Comment: A better constructor declaration is with initialization list:

struct coord {
  coord(int xvalue, int yvalue) : x(xvalue), y(yvalue) {}
  int x, y;
}

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are using would be valid C++0x ([uniform initializers](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#uniform-init)) and valid C99 (compound literals).
In C++03 you have to use either user-defined constructors or helper functions, the curly-brace syntax only works for [aggregate initialization](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=171).

If your struct is a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) and you need it to stay one, you have to use a helper function:

```
coord make_coord(int x, int y) {
    coord c = {x, y};
    return c;
}

UpdateB(make_coord(x, y));
```

Otherwise, as already mentioned, give it a constructor

Comment: I have seen before `UpdateB( (coord){1,2} )` working in g++ (no need for the helper function), but I doubt whether this is proper C++...

Comment: @David: In C++98/03 it isn't, g++ supports compound literals as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Pavel Radzivilovsky's solution is right (+1).

However you have to know that the coming new standart C++0x will allow the syntax of your example if you provide a constructor with two parameters (and maybe if you provide a constructor with initializer list but that's not useful here).

[This feature is already available in GCC starting v4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), if you use it you can enable it by enabling C++0x.